# Why is Chrome sending sec-ch-ua and sec-ch-ua-mobile request headers although "Experimental Web Platform features" are disabled

Tags: google-chrome, browser, http-headers, client-hints

I have the situation with Chrome, tested with `87.0.4280.88`, that in some cases Chrome will send `sec-ch-ua` and `sec-ch-ua-mobile` request headers, although `chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features` is set to "disabled".

For instance:

```
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="87", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="87"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
```

When this happens, the only way to get rid of these headers is to start Chrome with the parameter `--disable-features=UserAgentClientHint`.

Does someone have an explanation for this? As far as I understand, these features are still experimental and the specification in progress (https://wicg.github.io/ua-client-hints/).

Comment: Was looking everywhere for this: `--disable-features=UserAgentClientHint` thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a list of features behind the "Experimental Platform Features" flag, but I assume it's more about experimental **Chrome features** than experimental **web standards**, so that this flag probably was never intended to disable client hints, the maturity or stability of the standard behind it notwithstanding. Experimental standards get implemented all the time with current browsers, since that's the only way to get web developers' feedback on the practical implications of the standard.

According to Chrome's Platform Status, [client hints are enabled by default since Chrome 89](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5995832180473856) and seems to be a pre-requisite for the bigger issue of [`User-Agent` string reduction](https://blog.chromium.org/2021/05/update-on-user-agent-string-reduction.html), which is probably one of the reasons it has been implemented quickly.